# How do I stop a UICollectionView within A UITableViewCell go beyond bounds when more that one is initiated?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UITableView` that expands the height of each Cell and displays a `UICollectionView` when a cell is selected. It does all of the above with no errors, however, when I select one tableCell after the other and they are both expanded.
When the `UICollectionView`'s are populated with Cells and each has a different amount of items (so James has 3 insights and Tim has 4), when I expand the TableViewCell with less items in and then try and scroll Tim's `UICollectionView`, it exceeds beyond the bounds. This is because when I initiate a new collection view they both take on the `numberOfItemsInSection:` of the most recently created `UICollectionView`. I want the view created to maintain the `numberOfItemsInSection:` it had when it was originally created rather than all the `UICollectionView`'s adopting the most recent `numberOfItemsInSection:`. I hope this makes sense but I'll paste in my code for a better idea of what I mean, below is the code from the UITableViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
leaderboardCell *leaderCell = (leaderboardCell *) [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
isSelected = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath];
    if ([self cellIsSelected:indexPath]) {
        [leaderCell.collectionView removeFromSuperview];
        leaderCell.collectionView = nil;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"PostCellInformation" object:nil];
    } else {
if (isSelected) {
            leaderCell.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 65, 322, 200) collectionViewLayout:leaderCell.flowLayout];
            [leaderCell.collectionView registerClass:[userCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"userCellID"];
            leaderCell.flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
            [leaderCell.flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
            UIColor *collectionViewColour = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.17 green:0.28 blue:0.40 alpha:1.0];
            UIColor *borderColour = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.37 green:0.48 blue:0.60 alpha:1.0];
            [leaderCell.collectionView setBackgroundColor:collectionViewColour];
            [leaderCell.collectionView.layer setBorderColor:[borderColour CGColor]];
            [leaderCell.collectionView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
            [leaderCell.collectionView setDataSource:leaderCell];
            [leaderCell.collectionView setDelegate:leaderCell];
            }
 }
// Store cell 'selected' state keyed on indexPath
    NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
    [selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexPath];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

`leaderCell` is the `UITableViewCell` which contains the `UICollectionView`. I want each `UICollectionView`'s `numberOfItemsInSection:` to be applied to each one not all of them. Has anyone come across a similar problem? Thanks in Advance!

**EDIT** I have come to the conclusion that what I need to address to successfully achieve what I want here is to assign the dataSource to the right object,however, Im not sure what I need to assign it to... I basically need the dataSource to address each cell individually. At the moment my datasource is set to the TableViewCell which should be correct as it's assigned to each individual cell...